# Executing javascript, server side, nodejs in a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, server-side

I would want to build a prototype app similar to like [cloud9 ide](https://c9.io). What makes it cool is that you can run server side code using it, and I thought that would be quite risky.

1. How is this possible?
   Or atleast what's the concept on how **c9** able to execute and create server instance
2. Are there opensource projects that has the same feature using node.js?

Answer (score 1):

they probably use some kind of virtualisation to run server code, that way the code is contained (you might be able to use something like [LXC](http://linuxcontainers.org/) to achieve this).

[Cloud9 is actually open source](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9), and runs on node.js

Answer (score 1):

What @Ezequiel said, but also:

There is https://gf3.github.io/sandbox/, which spawns a new node process that executes the code in a restricted environment created with http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html.

Have a look at the source to get an idea:

- [`sandbox.js`](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/sandbox.js) spawns a new process running shovel.js and sends it code using STDIN
- [`shovel.js`](https://github.com/gf3/sandbox/blob/master/lib/shovel.js) creates a the environment to run the code

The executing process can run as a user with no rights.

ps. I'm not saying this is totally secure (vm doesn't claim to be that, see `vm.runInNewContext`)